# Query that references itself

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a self referencing and shifting basked of stocks (similar to methodologies used by S&P for the S&P 500). The goal is to create an index that changes structure every month. It guarantees a spot for the first stock by market cap (rank). The 2nd spot goes to the stock that has been in the previous months' lineup and ranks between 2 and 3 this month. If that stock ranks lower than 3, it will get excluded and a new stock slots into its' place. Else, the next closest stock will get chosen.

Give the table below, the index would include the following stocks:

2020-01-01 – AAPL + MSFT
2020-02-01 – AAPL + MSFT
2020-03-01 – APPL + GOOG

In my real data, I obviously have many more stocks and many more months. I am having a very hard time modeling the second case in Postgres since it requires me to create a continuously updated "previous months" table that I need to reference when checking the current month. Any idea how to do this in PostgreSQL? I tried recursive CTEs and those didn't work (due to inner join requirements)

Table with structure below.

| date | stock | rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | AAPL | 1 |
| 2020-01-01 | MSFT | 2 |
| 2020-01-01 | META | 3 |
| 2020-01-01 | GOOG | 4 |
| 2020-02-01 | AAPL | 1 |
| 2020-02-01 | MSFT | 3 |
| 2020-02-01 | META | 2 |
| 2020-01-01 | GOOG | 4 |
| 2020-03-01 | AAPL | 1 |
| 2020-03-01 | MSFT | 4 |
| 2020-03-01 | META | 3 |
| 2020-01-01 | GOOG | 2 |

Comment: Im not really sure if I get your question. But I think what you are looking for is a VIEW. Create a view with the data of the last month which you can use in your main query to decide the ranking of this month.

Comment: But what if I have 30 months? Then I need 30 views? I actually solved it with a very complex recursive query but it's not really ideal

Comment: So you need to update all your data every month? If thats the case its gonna get complicated either way. You can then use a recursive query or write a PL/pgSQL Function which loops all the data without recursion.

Comment: Any pointers for the looping query? I solved it now with a recursive query but it's quite complex